# Error when activating Project Web App Settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature-activation, project-server, project-online, pwa

I am attempting to activate the Project Web App Settings.

I navigate to the Settings Wheel > Site Settings > Site Collection Features. I then click the "Activate" button to the right of the Project Web App Settings feature and it redirects me to an error page with this information:

[image: Project Web App Settings feature error]

I am attempting to install Office 365 Project Portfolio Dashboard from the Office 365 store and it indicated I needed to turn on this feature.

Here are my environment specifics:

- SharePoint Online (O365)
- Publishing Site
- I am the site collection administrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be aware of the PWA setting **can not** be enabled on a `publishing site`, it only activated on the `Team Site` or `Project Site` template.

For more details check [Add Project Online to a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-Project-Online-to-a-site-collection-8accac79-9dc8-4167-8e0c-2c20fabcebdd)